# Extjs4 set Auth in a cross-domain ajax (jsonp) ajax request

Tags: extjs4, cross-domain, basic-authentication

I'm using Extjs4 and I have a problem with my store. How can I set "Basic Auth" in my proxy configuration? At this time when I load my application I get a login win...and I don't want that... Here the code:

```
Ext.define('DigitalPaper.store.DirTree', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model: 'DigitalPaper.model.DirTree',

proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url: alf_share_address+'proxy/alfresco/slingshot/doclib/treenode/node/alfresco/company/home/xxx',
    callbackKey: 'alf_callback',
    extraParams : {
        perms: false,
        children : false,
        max : 500,
        alf_ticket: alf_ticket
    },
    headers : { Authorization : "Basic "+Base64.encode('username:password')}
},

root: {
    text: 'Cartelle',
    id: 'src',
    expanded: true
}

});
```

Comment: Does `autoLoad` config help in your case?